# why when I put a comparison in the function it doesn't work as it should?

Tags: python

when i create a function without def, it works as it should, but when i create with def to add a recursion, it is already set to false.
can someone help me and tell me why this happens?

without the function working as it should

```
idade = int(input('digite a idade: '))
possui_experiencia = str(input("Possui experiencia? "))

if possui_experiencia == "não": 
   possui_experiencia = False
elif possui_experiencia == "sim":
   possui_experiencia = True
else: 
   print("Resposta invalida. digite sim ou não :")   
    
   
if possui_experiencia == True:
  anos_experiencia = int(input('digite quantos anos de experiencia:' )) 
  if idade < 18  :
     if   1<= anos_experiencia  <=2:
       hora_trabalho = 9.5
     elif anos_experiencia >= 3 :
       hora_trabalho = 11 

  else:  
     if 1<= anos_experiencia  <=2 :
       hora_trabalho = 9.5
     elif anos_experiencia >= 3 :
       hora_trabalho = 11 

  print('Valor do salario por hora é:',hora_trabalho)

else:
  if idade >= 18:
    hora_trabalho = 8.5
 
  else: hora_trabalho = 6.5

  print('Valor do salario por hora é :',hora_trabalho)
```

with a function ignoring everything and setting it to false.

```
idade = int(input('digite a idade: '))
possui_experiencia = 0

def funcao(possui_experiencia):
 possui_experiencia = (input("Possui experiencia? "))
 if possui_experiencia == "sim":
   possui_experiencia = True

 elif possui_experiencia == "não": 
   possui_experiencia = False
   
 else: 
   print("Resposta invalida. digite sim ou não :")
   funcao(possui_experiencia)

funcao(possui_experiencia)

if possui_experiencia == True:
  anos_experiencia = int(input('digite quantos anos de experiencia:' )) 
  if idade < 18  :
     if   1<= anos_experiencia  <=2:
       hora_trabalho = 9.5
     elif anos_experiencia >= 3 :
       hora_trabalho = 11 

  else:  
     if 1<= anos_experiencia  <=2 :
       hora_trabalho = 9.5
     elif anos_experiencia >= 3 :
       hora_trabalho = 11 

  print('Valor do salario por hora é:',hora_trabalho)

else:
  if idade >= 18:
    hora_trabalho = 8.5
 
  else: hora_trabalho = 6.5

  print('Valor do salario por hora é :',hora_trabalho)
```

I'm new to python and I don't really understand why it works without the function normally and when I put it in the function it doesn't work as it should

Comment: Because assigning to a parameter does not change the matching argument, even if they both happen to have the same name.

Comment: You need to `return` the value that your function computes instead of passing it in as a parameter and assigning to it.

Comment: Please read about local and global variables. Right now, the easiest way to solve this is to return some value from your funcao function. Consider changing def funcao(possui_experiencia) to def funcao(): and adding return possui_experiencia as your last line in this function.

Comment: Your code has a subtle bug (or at least unintended result), since you are reusing the name `possui_experiencia` for both the input and the boolean based on that input. If the user doesn't enter `não` or `sim`, you print a warning, but then continue on without changing the value of `possui_experiencia`. That will never match `True`, but will implicitly be treated the same as `False`.

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def funcao():
 possui_experiencia = (input("Possui experiencia? "))
 if possui_experiencia == "sim":
   return True

 elif possui_experiencia == "não": 
   return False
   
 else: 
   print("Resposta invalida. digite sim ou não :")
   return funcao()

possui_experiencia = funcao()
```

The reason it works is because the function returns a value and correctly uses local variables and variable scope, which you can learn about here:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables

Answer (score -1):

You need to `return` the value that your function computes instead of passing it in as a parameter and assigning to it.  The basic idea of a function is that it has an input (the parameter[s]) and an output (the return value).  You're trying to define it backwards by having the output in the spot where the input should go.  (It's possible to do this with a mutable parameter, but it's not usually the "right way" or the easy way.)

I.e. instead of:

```
possui_experiencia = 0

def funcao(possui_experiencia):
 possui_experiencia = (input("Possui experiencia? "))
 if possui_experiencia == "sim":
   possui_experiencia = True

 elif possui_experiencia == "não": 
   possui_experiencia = False
   
 else: 
   print("Resposta invalida. digite sim ou não :")
   funcao(possui_experiencia)

funcao(possui_experiencia)
```

do:

```
def funcao() -> bool:
    possui_experiencia = input("Possui experiencia? ")
    if possui_experiencia == "sim":
        return True
    elif possui_experiencia == "não": 
        return False
    else: 
        print("Resposta invalida. digite sim ou não :")
        return funcao()

possui_experiencia = funcao()
```